# volatile and atomic together. Does it make any sense?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, atomic, volatile

I noticed that all examples about atomic writes without `volatile` keyword. Surely it is right.

What will happen if I add the volatile modifier to my atomic link ?

Is there difference between :

```
public class VolatilAtomic {
    volatile AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
}
```

and

```
 public class VolatilAtomic {
         AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    }
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be a difference if you reassign the variable: `atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger()` in a method, in which case marking the variable as `volatile` will guarantee that the assignment will be visible by other threads.

But if you only use the `AtomicInteger` instance that is created with each instance of your class and never reassign it, then `volatile` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, `final` would be more appropriate.

The important thing about modifiers is that the alter the reference, not the object referenced.  e.g.

```
final int[] a = { 0 };
a[0] = 5;    // ok, not final
a = b;       // not ok as it is final
```

similarly

```
volatile int[] a = { 0 };
a[0] = 5;    // not a volatile write
a = b;       // volatile write.
```

Answer (score 0):

Both provide the same *visibility*, but only AtomicInteger provide *atomicity*.

Comment: Reading not just the title of a question sometimes is a good idea.